# How to use CASE clause (DB2) to display values from a different table?

Tags: db2, case

I'm working in a bank so I had to adjust the column names and information in the query to fit the external web, so if there're any weird mistakes know it is somewhat fine.

I'm trying to use the CASE clause to display data from a different table, I know this is a workaround but due to certain circumstances I'm obligated to use it, plus it is becoming interesting to figure out if there's an actual solution.

The error I'm receiving for the following query is:

> "ERROR [21000] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0811N The result of a scalar
>   fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more
>   than one row."

```
select  bank_num, branch_num, account_num, client_id,
CASE
    WHEN exists(
        select *
        from bank.services BS
        where ACCS.client_id= BS.sifrur_lakoach
        )

    THEN (select username from bank.services BS where BS.client_id = ACCS.client_id)
        ELSE 'NONE'
            END username_new
from bank.accounts accs
where bank_num = 431 and branch_num = 170
```

**EDIT:**
AFAIK we're using DB2 v9.7:
DSN11015 - DB21085I  Instance "DB2" uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL09075" with
level identifier "08060107".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v9.7.500.702", "s111017", "IP23287", and Fix Pack "5".

Comment: Check if you get more than 1 username for a single client_id in the THEN select query. Also, when using exists, just use 'select 1' instead of 'select *'.

Comment: That's the error, but there're so many records. And displaying the username in a JOIN works perfectly. I have no idea how to instruct the THEN clause to include all results, like an in() function.

Comment: Have you tired a left outer join?

Comment: So, if there are multiple `bank.services` rows for a given `BS.client_id`, which of them do you want to use for `username`?

Comment: the best possible way would be to post your sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Use listagg function to include all results.

```
select  bank_num, branch_num, account_num, client_id,
CASE
    WHEN exists(
        select *
        from bank.services BS
        where ACCS.client_id= BS.sifrur_lakoach
        )
    THEN (select   LISTAGG(username, ', ') from bank.services BS
         where BS.client_id = ACCS.client_id)
        ELSE 'NONE'
            END username_new
from bank.accounts accs
where bank_num = 431 and branch_num = 170
```

Comment: After reading LISTAGG's documentation it is undoubtly the answer. But unfortunately we're using an older DB2 version and LISTAGG isn't a recognized function.
DSN11015 - DB21085I  Instance "DB2" uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL09075" with
level identifier "08060107".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v9.7.500.702", "s111017", "IP23287", and Fix Pack "5".